# Internal phone storage in Android

Tags: android

How can you retrieve your phone internal storage from an app?  I found MemoryInfo, but it seems that returns information on how much memory use your currently running tasks.

I am trying to get my app to retrieve how much internal phone storage is available.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `android.os.Environment` to find the internal directory, then use `android.os.StatFs` to call the Unix `statfs` system call on it. Shamelessly [stolen](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/gingerbread/src/com/android/settings/deviceinfo/Memory.java#L335) from the Android settings app:

```
File path = Environment.getDataDirectory();
StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
long blockSize = stat.getBlockSize();
long availableBlocks = stat.getAvailableBlocks();
return Formatter.formatFileSize(this, availableBlocks * blockSize);
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a hard time having mine works. So I would like to share my working code to save some guys some time. 
Tested on a 32GB device and 1GB device.

```
// Return size is in Megabytes
public class DeviceMemory {

        public static long getInternalStorageSpace()
        {
            StatFs statFs = new StatFs(Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
            //StatFs statFs = new StatFs("/data");
            long total = ((long)statFs.getBlockCount() * (long)statFs.getBlockSize()) / 1048576;
            return total;
        }

        public static long getInternalFreeSpace()
        {
            StatFs statFs = new StatFs(Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
            //StatFs statFs = new StatFs("/data");
            long free  = ((long)statFs.getAvailableBlocks() * (long)statFs.getBlockSize()) / 1048576;
            return free;
        }

        public static long getInternalUsedSpace()
        {
            StatFs statFs = new StatFs(Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
            //StatFs statFs = new StatFs("/data");
            long total = ((long)statFs.getBlockCount() * (long)statFs.getBlockSize()) / 1048576;
            long free  = ((long)statFs.getAvailableBlocks() * (long)statFs.getBlockSize()) / 1048576;
            long busy  = total - free;
            return busy;
        }
}
```