# How to know internal memory size in android?

Tags: android, storage

This is my code,

```
private String memSize(String path){
    StatFs stat = new StatFs(path);
    long blockSize = stat.getBlockSize();
    long availableBlocks = stat.getAvailableBlocks();
    long freeBlocks = stat.getFreeBlocks();
    long countBlocks = stat.getBlockCount();
    String fileSize = Formatter.formatFileSize(this, availableBlocks * blockSize);
    String maxSize = Formatter.formatFileSize(this, countBlocks * blockSize);

    String info = path.toString()
                    + "\nblockSize : " + Long.toString(blockSize)
                    + "\navailableBlocks : " + Long.toString(availableBlocks)
                    + "\nfreeBlocks : " + Long.toString(freeBlocks)
                    + "\nreservedBlocks : " + Long.toString(freeBlocks - availableBlocks)
                    + "\ncountBlocks : " + Long.toString(countBlocks)
                    + "\nspace : " + fileSize + " / " + maxSize
                    + "\n\n";
    return info;
}
```

I test my function with path `/data` and `/sdcard` and it works
But when path is `/` (I understand it is root path), this is result.

- blockSize: 4096
- availableBlocks: 0
- freeBlocks: 0
- reservedBlocks: 0
- countBlocks: 0
- space: 0.00B / 0.00B

I think root path is SuperUser area. May need some permission to access.
My phone is already rooted. Could you show me what I should do next step ?

Thank you.

**References**

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StatFs.html
- [android internal phone storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652935/android-internal-phone-storage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your internal storage is not mounted in / it's in /data dir. [android internal phone storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652935/android-internal-phone-storage)

Comment: Thanks Risin, I think "/data" is internal space that allocated for user. But in my meaning "/" is total space in phone (OS+user).

Comment: You can try to run 'df' in android terminal - you'll se that / is not listed there. For some reason android is not providing info about /.