# How read and display available space in android both sd card and internal memory?

Tags: android, storage

how to programmatically read and display the size of sd-card and internal memory.

## Internal Memory

1. total space.
2. used  space.
3. free space.

## External Memory

1. total space.
2. used  space.
3. free space.

any related suggestions are apreciatted

Comment: before ask u have search first bcz there is so many answer already in stack over flow!!!!!!!

Comment: i have searched lot got code only to get sdcard available space

Comment: you may check, really nice solution. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8826357/2888952

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
public static long remainingLocalStorage()
{
StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getDataDirectory().getPath());
stat.restat(Environment.getDataDirectory().getPath());
long bytesAvailable = (long)stat.getBlockSize() *(long)stat.getAvailableBlocks();
return bytesAvailable;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
StatFs class
```

you can use here, provide the path for your internal and external directory and calculate the total, free and avialable space.

```
StatFs memStatus = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
```

See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StatFs.html) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Check this [Memory Status](http://www.androidsnippets.com/memory-size-class-for-viewing-available-storage)
class it has both methods to get Internal and external available storage