# Android camera space left

Tags: java, android, camera, space

I'm wondering if it's possible in the Android SDK to find the X amount of room for pictures or the Y amount of time for filming left. In the next link, for example, 1674 pictures can still be taken. Is that manually calculated by the amount of disk space left and the size of a picture maybe?
I've tried looking for solutions on this site and furthermore on google, but couldn't find anything about it...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sp4MD.png

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find free space amount like this:
[How to find the amount of free storage (disk space) left on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115016/how-to-find-the-amount-of-free-storage-disk-space-left-on-android)

But you still need to determine a picture size (or size of a 5-second video clip) experimentally.

There is no way to know picture size before compression.

Answer (score 0):

I'd first [check the available space on the SD card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394765/how-to-check-available-space-on-android-device-on-mini-sd-card) and then play around with it based on the quality of the picture taken or the video filmed.

By assigning a storage value to a picture quality - size you can calculate the amount of pictures you can still take with a simple division. Same goes for videos, but considering MB/sec.

You'll have to define those values tough, maybe by using the average size of a small group of pics.