# LibGDX - is this possible to get an amount of free storage space?

Tags: java, android, ios, libgdx, storage

There are some nice `I/O` & `Files` methods in LibGDX but I can't find any way to check the available space remaining on a device (Android, iOS, PC).

I'm downloading some files from the web and I need to tell the user how much space he needs.

Is it possible somehow? I've checked each of the methods connected with a `Files` interface. (I don't mean memory, I mean the physical space)

Thanks vm!

Comment: It's not a built-in LibGDX feature, but it can be done. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115016/how-to-find-the-amount-of-free-storage-disk-space-left-on-android  and here: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code

Comment: works like a charm! post as an answer and I'll accept!