# Android getExternalFilesDir vs getFilesDir() for big files

Tags: java, android

The difference between getExternalFilesDir and getFilesDir() is clear to me and well explained [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)).

In my case, since I need to keep files private and not accessible by user or other Apps (at least in non rooted device), getFilesDir() seems to be perfect. However I'm going to place big files there (let's say around 2Gb in total) and I would like to know if that folder/partition is typically capable enough for that purpose (I haven't found anything about that in the documentation).

**Edit:**

I've found some information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198440/is-there-a-maximum-size-to-android-internal-storage-allocated-for-an-app). It seems that modern devices sould have at least 1GB, but I still can't figure out what is the typical partition size on modern devices...

Answer (score 0):

Even having 20GB in data partition (not the same that internal storage that you show in the default file explorer) one app that waste 2GB is about 10% it have to be very important for me to keep it i use more of 10 apps .
and many telephones dont have 20GB.

To have 2GB in the internal storage of the device is to much for one app , many devices have 2GB or 4GB in Data partition, some have less and the point with apps is made to run in all devices as posible.

The data partition is used for the system apps to store data to if is full the system gets slow and malfunction. If the external storage is full is not the same.

If you want probide some security like "the data of this app can't be stealed unless you root the phone" You can store youre data in the external storage encripted, and save the key in the internal, to prevent other aplications to steal the data.