# File size limit for internal vs. external storage?

Tags: android, android-external-storage, internal-storage, android-internal-storage

I am looking for a best practice for considering internal vs. external storage depending on file size.

The [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#WriteInternalStorage) give no size reference for internal storage `getFilesDir()`, but 1MB for `getCacheDir()`:

> You should always maintain
>   the **cache files** yourself and stay within a reasonable limit of space
>   consumed, such as **1MB.**

Let's say an app needs to temporarily store video files, that are internal to the application. Assume 20 video files with 5MB each means 100MB total.

Is it reliable that the app can store 100MB in internal storage with `getFilesDir()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is there a maximum size to android internal storage allocated for an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198440/is-there-a-maximum-size-to-android-internal-storage-allocated-for-an-app)

Answer (score 1):

The [Android 9 Compatibility Definition](https://source.android.com/compatibility/android-cdd.html) says:

> Handheld device implementations:
>
> [7.6.1/H-0-1] MUST have at least **4 GB** of non-volatile storage
>   available for application private data (a.k.a. "/data" partition).

I believe this means that `getFilesDir()` is required to be at least 4 GB.

For Android 4.3:

> Device implementations MUST have at least **512MB** of non-volatile
>   storage available for user data. That is, the /data partition MUST be
>   at least 512MB.

Each Android version has a different amount of required storage space per app. If you are interested in the details, check out the other [ACDs](https://source.android.com/compatibility/cdd).