# How much amount of data can we store inside internal storage of an android app?

Tags: android, android-internal-storage

I am an android developer and developing an android app which will store data inside the internal storage of app i.e App-Specific Storage. I want to save files there because of privacy issues because I don't want any other apps to access my files. Can you please guide me how much data can I store there.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198440/is-there-a-maximum-size-to-android-internal-storage-allocated-for-an-app

Comment: That will depend on the device. Devices have different amounts of memory.

Answer (score 0):

for security issues, keep in mind to encrypt your files and then store them in internal storage.
Get free space of internal device with this code snipet :

```
long freeBytesInInternal = new File(ctx.getFilesDir().getAbsoluteFile().toString()).getFreeSpace();
```