# How to Check Internal Memory Storage count in android?

Tags: android, download, progress-bar, custom-controls

i Want to Iternal storage get Memory and used memory in progressbar in like in image below in my app.how to apply please help me custome progressbar used in android.and i used download app.[image]

Comment: Have You tried usual progress bar and two text views aligned to different sides?

Comment: yes i want to 2 textview inside  progressbar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how it can be accomplished:
TestActivity.java:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final TextView occupiedSpaceText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.occupiedSpace);
        final TextView freeSpaceText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.freeSpace);
        final ProgressBar progressIndicator = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        final float totalSpace = DeviceMemory.getInternalStorageSpace();
        final float occupiedSpace = DeviceMemory.getInternalUsedSpace();
        final float freeSpace = DeviceMemory.getInternalFreeSpace();
        final DecimalFormat outputFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

        if (null != occupiedSpaceText) {
            occupiedSpaceText.setText(outputFormat.format(occupiedSpace) + " MB");
        }

        if (null != freeSpaceText) {
            freeSpaceText.setText(outputFormat.format(freeSpace) + " MB");
        }

        if (null != progressIndicator) {
            progressIndicator.setMax((int) totalSpace);
            progressIndicator.setProgress((int)occupiedSpace);
        }
    }

    /**
     * From question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652935/android-internal-phone-storage by Lazy Ninja
     */
    public static class DeviceMemory {

        public static float getInternalStorageSpace() {
            StatFs statFs = new StatFs(Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
            //StatFs statFs = new StatFs("/data");
            float total = ((float)statFs.getBlockCount() * statFs.getBlockSize()) / 1048576;
            return total;
        }

        public static float getInternalFreeSpace() {
            StatFs statFs = new StatFs(Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
            //StatFs statFs = new StatFs("/data");
            float free  = ((float)statFs.getAvailableBlocks() * statFs.getBlockSize()) / 1048576;
            return free;
        }

        public static float getInternalUsedSpace() {
            StatFs statFs = new StatFs(Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
            //StatFs statFs = new StatFs("/data");
            float total = ((float)statFs.getBlockCount() * statFs.getBlockSize()) / 1048576;
            float free  = ((float)statFs.getAvailableBlocks() * statFs.getBlockSize()) / 1048576;
            float busy  = total - free;
            return busy;
        }
    }
}
```

layout/main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/memory_indicator_progress" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/occupiedSpace"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/freeSpace"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

drawable/memory_indicator_progress.xml:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_light" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

I'm not sure if it's exactly what You're looking for, but on my xperia v with 4.1 android I get the following picture:
[image]

On Your device colors might be different due to different platform.

Comment: Thanks Sandrstar for the reply i will check it.

Answer (score 0):

Use android.os.Environment to find the internal directory, then use android.os.StatFs to call the Unix statfs system call on it. Shamelessly [stolen](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/gingerbread/src/com/android/settings/deviceinfo/Memory.java#L335) from the Android settings app:

```
File path = Environment.getDataDirectory();
StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
long blockSize = stat.getBlockSize();
long availableBlocks = stat.getAvailableBlocks();
return Formatter.formatFileSize(this, availableBlocks * blockSize);
```

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652935/android-internal-phone-storage)

Comment: Thanks for Reply !!but how to set text in progress bar in android.used  memory color and available memory color in progress bar how to possible please help me!!!

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Utils {

public static float getInternalStorageSpace() {
    StatFs statFs = new StatFs(Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
    return ((float) statFs.getBlockCountLong() * statFs.getBlockSizeLong()) / 1048576;
}


public static float getInternalUsedSpace() {
    StatFs statFs = new StatFs(Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
    float total = ((float) statFs.getBlockCountLong() * statFs.getBlockSizeLong()) / 1048576;
    float free = ((float) statFs.getAvailableBlocksLong() * statFs.getBlockSizeLong()) / 1048576;
    return total - free;
}

public static float getUsedSpace() {
    StatFs statFs = new StatFs(Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
    return ((float) statFs.getAvailableBlocksLong() * statFs.getBlockSizeLong());
}

public static float getStorageSpace() {
    StatFs statFs = new StatFs(Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
    return ((float) statFs.getBlockCountLong() * statFs.getBlockSizeLong());
}


public static String readableFileTotalSize() {
    if (getStorageSpace() <= 0) return "0";
    final String[] units = new String[]{"B", "kB", "MB", "GB", "TB"};
    int digitGroups = (int) (Math.log10(getStorageSpace()) / Math.log10(1024));
    return new DecimalFormat("#,##0.#").format(getStorageSpace() / Math.pow(1024, digitGroups)) + " " + units[digitGroups];
}

public static String readableFileUseSize() {
    if (getUsedSpace() <= 0) return "0";
    final String[] units = new String[]{"B", "kB", "MB", "GB", "TB"};
    int digitGroups = (int) (Math.log10(getUsedSpace()) / Math.log10(1024));
    return new DecimalFormat("#,##0.#").format(getUsedSpace() / Math.pow(1024, digitGroups)) + " " + units[digitGroups];
}
```

}

```
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_100sdp"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">

            <TextView
                android:text="@string/file_manager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:textColor="?colorOnBackground"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_13sdp"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/cl_internal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_7sdp"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_internal">


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rl_support"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_8sdp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

                    <com.google.android.material.progressindicator.CircularProgressIndicator
                        android:id="@+id/pb_progress"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        app:indicatorSize="@dimen/_45sdp"
                        app:trackColor="?android:colorBackground"
                        app:indicatorColor="?colorPrimary"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_image"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_25sdp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sdp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_8sdp"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/list_sort"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_sdcard" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_title"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:text="@string/internal_storage"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_13sdp"
                    android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                    android:ellipsize="middle"
                    android:includeFontPadding="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_13sdp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_content"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/rl_support"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/iv_menu"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_content"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:includeFontPadding="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_13sdp"
                    android:textColor="?android:textColorHint"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/rl_support"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_title"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/iv_menu"/>


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_menu"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_right"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_8sdp"
                    android:background="?actionBarItemBackground"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/list_sort"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>





  final float totalSpace = Utils.getInternalStorageSpace();
    final float occupiedSpace = Utils.getInternalUsedSpace();
    CircularProgressIndicator indicator = binding.pbProgress;
    indicator.setMax((int) totalSpace);
    indicator.setProgress((int)occupiedSpace);

    String total =  Utils.readableFileUseSize()+" free / "+Utils.readableFileTotalSize();

    binding.tvContent.setText(total);
```